# should I use "make some location" or "make it to some location"?

Tags: idiomatic-language

Which of the following sounds more natural to native speakers?

> I can make it to the library today

or

> I can make the library today

Comment: Definitely "I can make it to the library"

Comment: The second could be used more approriately in: "I can make the morning train."